# Executing AWS Cloud Watch APIs through HTTP requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am currently trying to execute the **AWS cloud watch APIs** and get the logs from the cloud watch environment. I have successfully implemented this by using the SDK provided by AWS. Also in the documentations they mentioned that we can also use HTTP requests to get the logs from cloud watch. In the following documentation they have mentioned the params that we have to pass from the request.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html.

The problem is there are also some common params to be sent from the request. I need to clarify the way that we want to send them. As query params, path params or request headers?

Answer (score 1):

The request parameters for the **Cloud Watch Rest API** should be sent in the JSON format inside the `{}`, similar to the way in the POST example given. Of these only `logGroupName` is required, while the other paramaters mentioned are optional:

**

```
endTime 
filterPattern
interleaved
limit
logGroupName
logStreamNamePrefix
logStreamNames
nextToken
startTime
```

**

In the context of the entire HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: logs.<region>.<domain>
X-Amz-Date: <DATE>
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<Credential>, SignedHeaders=content-type;date;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target;x-amzn-requestid, Signature=<Signature>
User-Agent: <UserAgentString>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
Content-Length: <PayloadSizeBytes>
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Amz-Target: Logs_20140328.FilterLogEvents
 {
   "endTime": number,
   "filterPattern": "mystring",
   "interleaved": boolean,
   "limit": number,
   "logGroupName": "string",
   "logStreamNamePrefix": "string",
   "logStreamNames": [ "string" ],
   "nextToken": "string",
   "startTime": number
}
```

---

The Common Parameters are sent as HTTP params as seen in the example above. They are needed here for signing your requests to AWS with the proper authentication. 
(Authentication occurs automatically in the background when using the CLI)
[This is an official walkthrough of how to construct a canonical,signed HTTP request for AWS APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)

For example:

```
Action=ListUsers&
Version=2010-05-08&
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=AKIDEXAMPLE%2F20150830%2Fus-east-1%2Fiam%2Faws4_request&
X-Amz-Date=20150830T123600Z&
X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost%3Bx-amz-date
```

Comment: There are also some params called common params. Don't we need to send them through the request? This is regarding to the above comment. The payload which contains the log details should be sent as a JSON payload. What about the other params? Param "Host" to param "X-Amz-Target". Should all these params should be sent through header?

Comment: The common params are for authentication, among other things(see above). The host header is needed to scepify a region and a domain

Comment: I am trying with Postman currently. It has an authentication header called "AWS Signature". For testing purposes we can use that by adding the AccessKey and SecretKey right? Or do we need to go through the whole process of executing the HTTP requests with signing?

Comment: You can definitely use Postman for testing this. This is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html